# python shutil.move moves directories with files fix

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I was programming in python and I got something that I cannot fix. I have this code:

```
import shutil
import pathlib
import os

zdroj =(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\New')
cil =(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\New2')

files = os.listdir(zdroj)
print(files)
print (files)
for f in files:
        c = (r'\'' + f)
        c = c.split("'")
        shutil.move(str(zdroj) + c[0], str(cil))
```

But it move the folder too, anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import shutil
import pathlib
import os

zdroj =(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\New')
cil =(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\New2')

files = os.listdir(zdroj)
print(files)
for f in files:
        src = os.path.join(zdroj, f)
        shutil.move(src, str(cil))
```

Comment: Dude thanks, it is working but where i have the mistake? I will accept the answer then

Comment: When you did `c = (r'\'' + f)` and then `c = c.split("'")` you made `c[0]` have only the slash `\\`, then your source folder was the root directory